# Connecting our first tape drive (SAS) to SATA bus

Tags: backup, sas, sata, tapedrive, lto

Our small team is considering buying our first tape drive for backups. However, we are still lacking serious enterprise-grade servers and have to rely temporarily on SATA drives in our rigs. Cost considerations argue against setting up a high-end automatic tapeloader, so our purchasing manager decided to go with a SAS tape drive (LTO 3 or LTO 4) to allow for migration to higher-end gear in the future.

What else do we need besides a SAS backplane and a reverse breakout cable to connect the tape drive to SATA bus on our boxes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Connecting a SAS tape drive to a SATA port will not work.**

 They are different protocols. [Here's a primer](https://serverfault.com/questions/510442/how-exactly-does-a-sas-sff-8087-breakout-cable-work-raid-connection-questions/510445#510445).

Can you provide information on the hardware involved?

- What type of server(s) are you using?
- What tape drive did you purchase? Some tape drives come [bundled with the necessary HBA](http://h71016.www7.hp.com/MiddleFrame.asp?page=config&ProductLineId=450&FamilyId=1249&BaseId=21896&oi=E9CED&BEID=19701&SBLID=) to accommodate host-connectivity.
- Is this an internal or external drive?

If using an external SAS tape drive, you should use a dedicated and [purpose-built SAS host bus adapter](http://www.lsi.com/products/storagecomponents/Pages/LSISAS3442E-R.aspx) (HBA) with an external SAS [SFF-8088](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:SFF_8088.jpg) or [SFF-8470](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:SFF_8470.jpg) port.

[image]

Comment: Have not bought yet, going for an external drive - Quantum, Tandberg and HP AFAIK are on the menu. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: There are HP LTO3/Ultrium 920 drive packages that include the cabling and SAS adapter needed to run. Look for HP part #AG738A.