# Difference between SAS multilane, direct-attached HDD and expander backplane?

Tags: sas, supermicro, hardware

What's the difference between **multilane**, **direct-attached HDD** and **expander** for SAS backplanes?

> [Supermicro chassis description page](http://www.supermicro.com/products/chassis/3u/)
>
> Direct attached HDD backplane (TQ version), multilane backplane (A version) and expanders' backplane (E1, E2 versions) are available for application specific solution optimization.

I'm guessing that direct-attached requires me to use a SFF-8087 fanout cable to each 4 disks, while multilane only requires 1 SFF-8087-to-SFF-8087 cable for each 4 disks, and finally an expander backplane allows me to use 1 SFF-8087-to-SFF-8087 for more than 4 disks?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, that's all correct. I suppose it's not clear from the Supermicro product pages.

SAS [SFF-8087](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:SFF_8087.jpg) is a 4-lane multi-connection transport. It's typically used by RAID controllers and disk backplanes. You probably want to avoid anything that requires fanout cables. Expander backplanes *can* have some problems, depending on what types of disks and controllers will be in use.

Also this: [How exactly does a SAS SFF-8087 breakout cable work? + RAID/connection questions](https://serverfault.com/questions/510442/how-exactly-does-a-sas-sff-8087-breakout-cable-work-raid-connection-questions/510445#510445)

Answer (score 1):

The cable you'll use is dependent on the drive backplane and the disk controller you use. If both of them are SFF-8087, you can get an SFF-8087 straight cable, otherwise you might have to use a fan-out cable.

Comment: Also, if you're using a SAS expander, you'll have one incoming SFF-8087 (depending on the expander) and output with probably more SFF-8087 cables.