# Is it possible to use a HP P410 Controller in a ML150 Gen5 server? i.e. is there a cable that interfaces with a Gen5 cage?

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, sas, hp-smart-array

Specifically I want to use a SAS card (a P410) and some drives that I have spare in a ML150 Gen5 server.

If there is a cable that converts mini SAS to the Gen5 SAS cage connection can someone point me to it?

Or can I use a ML150 Gen6 cage in a ML150 Gen5 server?

I think the cage part number is 458312-B21 for the Gen5 and 487737-B21 for the Gen6 but correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Okay. I'll bite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sure**: [*All-things-SAS*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_attached_SCSI) - Also [see this](https://serverfault.com/questions/510442/how-exactly-does-a-sas-sff-8087-breakout-cable-work-raid-connection-questions).

- The 4-bay 3.5" disk backplane for the HP ProLiant ML150 G5 drive cage (part 451781-001) uses a single older-generation four-lane [SAS SFF-8484](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:SFF_8484_angled.jpg) connector.
- The HP Smart Array P410 controller features *two* four-lane [SAS SFF-8087](http://www.ocp.com/product_search/images/products/photos/70991.jpg) ports.
- You will need a [***SAS SFF-8484 Male to SFF-8087 Male***](http://www.attotech.com/products/product.php?cat=&scat=18&prod=62) cable.

[image]