# SAS connector = 4x SATA automatically?

Tags: hardware, sas, sata

So I've been looking at server board and I often see some of them having a SAS connector. Base on my previous experience with SAS (Dell Perc6i), I can connect a SAS-to-4xSATA cable so I can use normal drives.

Is this true for all SAS connectors or perhaps these are limited to certain connectors/controllers like the one on the Perc6i?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

If the SAS port is a multilane (4x) one, you *should* be able to use a SATA breakout cable without problems.

For more information, give a look at [that serverfault question.](https://serverfault.com/questions/510442/how-exactly-does-a-sas-sff-8087-breakout-cable-work-raid-connection-questions)